# Will a SHA256 hash always have 64 characters?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, sha256

I'm setting up my database to receive hashed passwords and not accept plain text.

Would I go something like this?

```
create table User(
username varchar(20) not null,
password varchar(64) not null,
);
```

Comment: I know this was asked 12 years ago at this point, but I'd like to point out that hashed passwords using sha256 are _not_ best practice now and also weren't in 2010. You should use an algorithm suited for passwords such as bcrypt, plus use a salt, and probably use a module for that instead of rolling your own

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Yes, a SHA256 is always 256 bits long, equivalent to 32 bytes, or 64 bytes in an hexadecimal string format. You can even use char(64) instead of varchar(64) since the size won't change.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it will always have 64 characters.